# Scan network settings from inside (pretend to be outside)

Tags: networking, nmap

Is this possible? With nmap or similar tools? Basically I've setup NAT and security policies on my private network. Now I need to test them. Ideally I want to test them from my PC (that is on the private network).

E.g. I enabled SSH on a certain local machine (TCP 22) and setup forwarding to from my router port 8022 to local machine IP:22.

Doing `nmap <my_public_ip>` does not work from within the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a standard home router? Probably not.

You need the ability to do hair-pinning - which allows traffic to appear to be coming from the external IP when in fact it's originating within the network. While you may get this ability on enterprise routers, it's unlikely that you'll be able to do it on a standard home router.

Instead, look at getting a cheap server, which you can use for a few hours to do your testing from. This way you'll genuinely be testing your service as if you're connecting from outside (as you will be) and can confirm everything as it should be.